# Не работают функции в шаблоне woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Пытаюсь к кастомному шаблону woocommerce прикрепить get_header()(после открывающего тега

```
   <body>
```

) и get_footer()(перед закрывающим тегом

```
 </body>
```

). После перезагрузки вместо страницы белый экран, в консоли ошибок нет. Если закомментировать get_header(), то страница с контентом отображается, но сам футер не отображается, хотя я не комментировал его. Так же попытался в том же месте (после

```
<body>
```

) вызвать функцию get_current_user_id(), после чего страница снова стала белой, из этого сделал вывод, что вызов каких-либо функций wordpress что-то нарушает в шаблоне, из-за чего контент не хочет отображаться. P.S. Если напечатать echo "Какой-то текст"; то этот текст отображается и контент шаблона тоже.

P.S.S.Кстати в другом кастомном шаблоне(на этом же сайте) get_header() и get_footer() прекрасно работают.

Comment: >белый экран, в консоли ошибок нет.  Белый экран - это ВСЕГДА ошибки. См логи. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD

Comment: @SeVlad  в логах ничего не было, хотя WP_DEBUG был активен, но все равно спасибо, проблему решил.

Comment: Если и в логах нет (что вряд ли) - значит в конфиге не разрешен вывод ошибок. Это нужно исправлять.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом: создал новый шорткод, в котором подключил свой php файл, потом в админке создал новую страницу и в нее вставил свой шорткод, теперь все работает.